# Textbook reference for ergodicity condition for stationary sequences?

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes, ergodic-theory

In a set of lecture notes, I have the following result:

> **Theorem**. Let $X_n$ be random variables on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ with values in a Polish metric space $S$. Suppose $X = (X_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is a stationary sequence. Then $X$ is ergodic if and only if for any bounded Borel measurable function $g: S^p \to \mathbb{R}$ with $p \geq 1$ an arbitrary integer,
> $$\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}g(X_{m+1}, \dots, X_{m+p}) \overset{a.s.}{\to} \mathbb{E}[g(X_1, \dots, X_p)]\text{.}$$

Note that $\overset{a.s.}{\to}$ denotes almost sure convergence as $n \to \infty$.

I have been trying to find this result in the 20-30 measure-theoretic probability books I have to no avail, as well as *An Introduction to Ergodic Theory* by Walters. Does anyone know of a textbook where I can find this result? I would strongly prefer a reference with a proof, but would be willing to take those without as well.

**Edit**: Adding definitions as requested.

Given $X$ above, it is ergodic if for any invariant set $A \in \mathcal{F}$, $\mathbb{P}(A) \in \{0, 1\}$.

By "invariant set," we say a set $A \in \mathcal{F}$ is invariant with respect to $X$ if for some $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{\infty})$ ($\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{\infty})$ denoting the Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$), $A = \{(X_n, X_{n+1}, X_{n+2}, \dots)\} \in B$ for all $n \geq 1$.

[I suspect that $S^{\infty}$ should be used in place of $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ in the above definitions and that $\in$ should be $\subset$, but that's how they are presented in the lecture notes.]

**Edit 2**: I found this claim in some other sources, though not in great detail. It would be nice to find a textbook.

- Last sentence of [http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/6712-14/6712-14-Notes-Ergodic.pdf](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Eks20/6712-14/6712-14-Notes-Ergodic.pdf)
- [Appendix A](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/9780470670057.app1) of *GARCH Models: Structure, Statistical Inference and Financial Applications* uses the theorem above as the definition of an ergodic stationary process. This passage cites Billingsley (1995), which I assume is *Probability and Measure* - but I know that this theorem is not in there.

Comment: maybe it's just a [folklore](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/116019/inadmissible-theorems-in-research/116035#116035) ?

Comment: @BCLC I wouldn't know, unfortunately. There is a proof in these lecture notes that I haven't had time to closely examine. I'm interested in these textbooks not for the proof of this result, but because if they cover this result, I expect that the material surrounding it would be of interest to me.

Comment: What is your definition of ergodic here?

Comment: @Adam Edit made above with definitions, thanks.

Comment: Do we think $p \geq 1$ is necessary? It seems like a restatement of the ergodic theorem (say 6.2.1 in Durrett), followed by some argument about if $E[f(X) | I] = E[f(X)]$ for a sufficiently large class of functions $f$, then $I$ is trivial. (Suppose not and take $f$s to be indicators on sets in $I$.) I don't have a proof, but just these observations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the case $p=1$ (allowing for $p>1$ seems unnecessary). By Birkhoff's ergodic theorem ([http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2016/REUPapers/Ran.pdf](http://math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/REU2016/REUPapers/Ran.pdf) , Theorem 7.1), for any measurable and bounded $g$, the following convergence holds almost surely:
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n g(X_i) \to \mathbb{E}[g(X_1) |\mathcal{I}],$$
where $\mathcal{I}$ is the $\sigma-$algebra of invariant sets. From the definition of conditional expectation
$$\mathbb{E}[g(X_1) |\mathcal{I}] = \mathbb{E}[g(X_1)] \qquad \forall g \text{ measurable + bounded }$$
is equivalent to $\mathcal{I}$ being the trivial $\sigma-$algebra, which is in turn equivalent to ergodicity.

Answer (score 2):

This result is provided, without proof, as Theorem 5.6(e) of *A First Course in Stochastic Processes*, 2nd ed., by Karlin and Taylor (1975).

I don't have this book, but *Stationary and Related Stochastic Processes: Sample Function Properties and Their Applications* by Cramer and Leadbetter (2004) might have some information there. I will edit this post if I find out whether or not this result is mentioned in there.